# Getting offsetTop of element in a table

Tags: javascript, html, offset

I can't seem to figure out how to get the offsetTop of an element within a table. It works fine on elements outside tables, but all of the elements within a table return the same result, and it's usually at the top of the page. I tried this in Firefox and Chrome. How do I get the offsetTop of an element in a table?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`offsetTop` returns a value relative to `offsetParent`; you need to recursively add `offsetParent.offsetTop` through all of the parents until `offsetParent` is `null`.  Consider using [jQuery](http://jQuery.com)'s [`offset`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset)`()` method.

**EDIT**: If you don't want to use jQuery, you can write a method like this (untested):

```
function offset(elem) {
    if(!elem) elem = this;

    var x = elem.offsetLeft;
    var y = elem.offsetTop;

    while (elem = elem.offsetParent) {
        x += elem.offsetLeft;
        y += elem.offsetTop;
    }

    return { left: x, top: y };
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in IE7 (reliably).  IE5-7 doesn't count elements with relative positioning as offsetParents.

Comment: @SLaks brilliant solution :)

Comment: Thank you. Still good in 2022.

/Jesper