# Why won't mouse events fire when a canvas element is inside a table control?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, canvas

I'm having trouble getting mouse events to work properly when a canvas control is nested inside of a table control which I've used in a custom user control for my ASP.net web page. Here is essentially the only UI code in file:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="200"></canvas>
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

And the JavaScript code that controls the mousedown event:

```
//...

//controls drag behavior
var dragok = false;
var x;
var y;

//...

function myDown(e) {
    if (e.layerX < 50 + canvas.offsetLeft && e.layerX > 0 +
    canvas.offsetLeft  && e.layerY < y + 25 + canvas.offsetTop &&
    e.layerX > y - 25 + canvas.offsetTop) {
        x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

        dragok = true;
        canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
    }
}

//...
```

When I try to click and drag inside my canvas, nothing happens. I can't tell if the event isn't firing or if it's some other problem. Thoughts?

Comment: It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/Ht3xx/1/ Can you post a fiddle where it does not?

Comment: Weird, it works on jsfiddle for me as well. I am using ASP.net for my development, is it possible that it has something to do with this? I will update the question.

Comment: I figured out a solution and I'll post the answer when the question gets taken off hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out that the problem had to do with the offsetLeft and offsetTop properties of the canvas I was working with. For some reason, this only seems to be a problem within ASP.net, because as Cristy posted in his comment, the code works just fine when outside of an ASP context. To fix my problem, I consulted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044988/getting-offsettop-of-element-in-a-table); I wrote a recursive function to get the parent element's offset value and then used that to fix the offset value I was using for the mouse event.

```
function offset(elem)
{
    if (!elem) elem = this;

    var x = elem.offsetLeft;
    var y = elem.offsetTop;

    while(elem = elem.offsetParent)
    {
        x += elem.offsetLeft;
        y += elem.offsetTop;
    }

    return { left: x, top: y }
}

//...

function myDown(e) {
    if (e.layerX < 50 + offset(canvas).left &&
        e.layerX > offset(canvas).left &&
        e.layerY < 200 + offset(canvas).top &&
        e.layerY > offset(canvas).top) {

        x = e.pageX - offset(canvas).left;
        y = e.pageY - offset(canvas).top;

        document.getElementById("coord").value = Math.floor((200 - y) / 20);

        dragok = true;
        canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
    }
}
```

Via above link: "`offsetTop` returns a value relative to `offsetParent`; you need to recursively add `offsetParent.offsetTop` through all of the parents until `offsetParent` is `null`